# Batch script to find duplicate filenames in the same dictionary

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, duplicates

I need to find files with the same names in the same directory and print their names and return some error code.
It works fine at this point, but the filenames are printed several times. I did it in a rather primitive way.

fol2 contains files:

```
Abc123
BBBB
CCCC
CCCCaaa
CCCCbbb
CCCCrrr
```

My output:

```
CCCCaaa
CCCCbbb
CCCCrrr
CCCC
CCCCbbb
CCCCrrr
CCCC
CCCCaaa
CCCCrrr
CCCC
CCCCaaa
CCCCbbb
```

Expected result:

```
CCCCaaa
CCCCbbb
CCCCrrr
CCCC
```

My Code:

```
@ECHO Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    for /R C:\Users\operator\Desktop\batch\fol2 %%a in (*.*) do (

        set fileDic1=%%~nxa
        set fileConcatPart1Dic1=!fileDic1:~0,3%!
        set fileConcatPart2Dic1=!fileDic1:~3%!
    
        for /R C:\Users\operator\Desktop\batch\fol2 %%b in (*.*) do (
    
            set fileDic2=%%~nxb
            set fileConcatPart1Dic2=!fileDic2:~0,3%!
            set fileConcatPart2Dic2=!fileDic2:~3%!
            REM echo !fileConcatPart1Dic1!
            REM echo !fileDic2!
            if !fileConcatPart1Dic1!==!fileConcatPart1Dic2! (if not !fileConcatPart2Dic1!==!fileConcatPart2Dic2! (echo %%~nxb)) 
        
        )

    )
```

I know that similar topics have appeared, but I want to evaluate my code and get advice on how to do it in a different, better, and maybe easier way.

Comment: The first advice I'd give you is to use for variable expansion modifiers. You can see those available by reading to output from `for /?`, in a Command Prompt window. This means instead of using `somevariablei=!anothervariablei:~0,3%!` for the drive letter part and `somevariablei=!anothervariablei:~3%!` for all except the drive letter part,  you could use `somevariablei=%%~da` and `somevariablei=%%~pa` instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do you have two nested loops iterating over the same directory tree? Why you are splitting off the first three characters of each file name and check them for equality, while you check the remainder for inequality?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="


    for /R C:\Users\operator\Desktop\batch\fol2 %%a in (*.*) do (

        set fileDic1=%%~nxa
        set fileConcatPart1Dic1=!fileDic1:~0,3%!
        set fileConcatPart2Dic1=!fileDic1:~3%!
    
        for /R C:\Users\operator\Desktop\batch\fol2 %%b in (*.*) do (
    
            set fileDic2=%%~nxb
            set fileConcatPart1Dic2=!fileDic2:~0,3%!
            set fileConcatPart2Dic2=!fileDic2:~3%!
            REM echo !fileConcatPart1Dic1!
            REM echo !fileDic2!
            if !fileConcatPart1Dic1!==!fileConcatPart1Dic2! if not !fileConcatPart2Dic1!==!fileConcatPart2Dic2! if not defined #%%~nxb (
               echo %%~nxb
               set "#%%~nxb=Y"
            ) 
        
        )

    )
```

This *should* work for you.

The changes are: 
The `for /f...set # ...` which should remove any variables starting with `#` from the environment (unlikely to be any, but this makes sure)
Removed the parentheses around the `if not...` condition - you can cascade `if` statements if you are not using `else` clauses.
Added a third `if` to detect whether the variable `#%%~nxb` has been set. if it isn't set, then it will be set when the name is `echo`ed. Since it is then set (to a non-empty value) it will fail the `not defined` test and hence the name will not be repeated.